# I'm trying to write a c program for sin x using Taylor series but not being able to figure out my mistake while executing the program

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop, taylor-series

Firstly I have defined pi  and a function called *fact* for finding factorial values.
Using Taylor series we have sin(x)= x-(x^3)/3! + (x^5)/5! - ....... upto 10th term.
*nemo* is the abbreviation for numerator and *deno* for denominator for the following terms.
Value stores the value of sin(x).

Here's the code that I have tried writing:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

#define pi 3.142

int fact(int);

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    float x, value, nume, deno;
    printf("Enter the value for sin x in degrees: \t");
    scanf("%f", &x);
    x= (pi * x)/100;
    value = 0;
    i=1;
    while(i== 1)
        value = value+ x;
    i = 2;
    for(i=2; i<=10; i++)
    {
        while (i%2 !=0)
        {

            nume = pow(x,i);
            deno = fact(i);
            for(j = 2; j<i; j++)

                if(j%2 == 0)
                value = value - (nume/deno);
            else
                value = value + (nume/deno);

            nume = 0;
            deno = 0;
        }

    }
    printf("value of sin x is : \t");
    printf("%f", value);
    return 0;
}

int fact(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return (n*fact(n-1));
}
```

Not being able to figure out what's going wrong. When I'm executing it only prints **Enter the value of sin x in degrees** Please help me to fix this code.

Comment: In your own words, why should the `while (i%2 !=0)` loop stop? What happens *inside that loop* to cause the value of `i` to change? Or do you expect that the loop can exit for some other reason? Why? How?

Comment: Also, please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ so that you won't have to depend on others for small issues like this every time.

Comment: I could bear `#define pi 3.142`, but `x = (pi * x) / 100;` is just wrong (typo? 100 -> 180). Besides, It's unclear what you think `i=1; while(i == 1) value = value+ x; i = 2;` does, but surely it doesn't update `value` only one time. The statement `i=2;` is outside the body of the `while` loop (try to always use brackets), so it's never changed causing an infinite loop (UB). The whole thing should just be `float value = x;`.

Comment: Your loop with j is complicated and may be not working as expected when the only test is to check if ((i-1)/2)%2 == 0 for + operation

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  Thanks a lot! I quite understood what mistake I was making.

Comment: @Bob__ yeah typo.   Thank you!